# Amqp test framework - write tests without coding

Tags: rest, kendo-ui, karate, amqp

We have being succesfully using Karate framework for testing REST APIs.
Now we need to test also AMQP communication. What we need is (priority wise listed) either

1. Continue to use Karate. How can this be done? Do we need yo write the step implementations?
2. Identify a similar tool for testing AMQP without dev skills, without having to write code. Found Kendo (https://tech-blog.lectra.com/article/763-testing-amqp-apis) but cannot find more information about it.
3. Create our own C# specflow solution but this requires developer knowledge.